# Error compiling ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG()

Tags: spring-boot, jfreechart, jfreereport

I get this error:

> ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(path), chart, 300, 300);
>
> The method saveChartAsJPEG(java.io.File, org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart, int, int)
> in the type ChartUtilities is not applicable for the arguments
> (org.apache.tomcat.jni.File, org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart, int, int)

Here is my code:

```
package com.manish.location.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.tomcat.jni.File;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;

public class ReportUtilImpl implements ReportUtil {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void generatePieChart(String path, List<Object[]> data) {
        DefaultPieDataset dataset= new DefaultPieDataset();
        
        for(Object[] object:data) {
            dataset.setValue(object[0].toString(), new Double(object[1].toString()));
            
        }
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Location Type Report", dataset);
        try {
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(path), chart, 300, 300);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting above error. Please fix it; it's about report utility program. I am using [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) API.

Comment: error in the line =ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(path), chart, 300, 300);

Comment: In a servlet context, try one of the [`ChartUtils`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtils.html) that writes to an `OutputStream`.